# laravel model class not found

Tags: laravel, models

I'm getting class model not found error

In my model class

```
namespace App\models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



 class Customer extends Model
{
protected $table = 'customers';  
}
```

And in my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use \app\Models\Customer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class RoomsController extends Controller
  {
 public function index()
{
    $room= Customer::all();
    return view('rooms',compact('room'));

}

}
```

I even tried `composer dump-autoload`.
I'm still getting the same error

Comment: By the way, if you develop Laravel app - you should follow Laravel conventions.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak which are?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, models in Laravel lay in App namespace, not App\Models (and for sure not inside App\models).

Answer (score 1):

Use use in head of your controller

```
use App\models\Customer;
```

Than you can call it in your function:

```
Customer::find($id);//etc
```

Comment: somewhat I think my slashes are in the wrong direction, but if it works, you are welcome :)

Comment: Yes it was :-) I changed it, so no problem

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\Customer;
```

Use this in head of the controller

Comment: But the `Customer` class is inside of `\App\models` namespace. So it would be: `use App\models\Costumer;`

Comment: Oh, i didn't notice. Thanks.